# How do I calculate the (maximum) circulating supply for a given block height?

Tags: reward, block-reward

I would like to be able to calculate the circulating/max supply at any given point in time (for a specified block height).

I know that the current block reward is 3 ETH (soon to be reduced to 2 ETH).  When I multiply the current block height (6471790) by 3, I get a number (19415370) that is very short of what most block explorers report as the circulating/max supply (102,426,590).  Even if I factor in uncle rewards, I still don't come anywhere close.

I know that ETH had a pre-mine, and an ICO. Is it necessary to factor these numnbers into my calculation?

thanks!

Comment: Eh this is probably a duplicate of: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/how-to-query-the-amount-of-mining-reward-from-a-certain-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you've missed is that the block reward was 5 ETH between blocks 0 and 4,370,000. At that point the block reward was reduced to 3 as part of the Byzantium hard fork, under [EIP-649](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/669).

That should give you another 2 * 4,370,000 => 8,740,000 ETH.

Without seeing how you've calculated the uncle and transaction rewards, the above extra may or may not get you significantly closer to the total.

---

**Edit:**

> I know that ETH had a pre-mine, and an ICO. Is it necessary to factor these numbers into my calculation?

Yes.

To quote a [previous answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46708/52):

> You'll see from EtherScan that the presale of 72M ETH was split into
>   "60M Crowdsale + 12M Other". The 12M ETH was kept by the Ethereum
>   Foundation, which at the time was ~17% of the total. This now accounts
>   for ~13% of the total..

Which is referring to [this](https://etherscan.io/stat/supply) EtherScan page showing the total supply of ETH. From the EtherScan page you'll see that to get the total you're after you'll need to include both the crowdsale and the amount kept by the foundation:

```
ETHER DISTRIBUTION OVERVIEW
Genesis (60M Crowdsale 12M Other):  72,009,990.50 Ether
+ Mining Block Rewards: 28,263,028.50 Ether
+ Mining Uncle Rewards: 2,170,325.38 Ether
= Current Total Supply
102,443,344.37 Ether
```

I think 72,009,990.50 is the value you're probably after. (So the 12M value is only approximate, as is the 60M value, which you've found.)

Comment: This gets me closer for sure, but it's clear I need the pre-mine numbers.  I've found 60,102,216 for the pre-sale, but there was also some number around 12 million that I can't find.  Is this documented anywhere?